# stdio redirect "fails" when calling waveInOpen, why?

Tags: winapi, stdout, winmm

Here's my basic program, it should compile fairly easily with VisualStudio (even express).

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

HWAVEIN hWaveIn;
WAVEFORMATEX WaveFormat;
WAVEHDR WaveHeader;

typedef union
{
    uint32_t u32;
    struct 
    {
        int16_t iLeft;
        int16_t iRight;
    };
}   audiosample16_t;

#define AUDIORATE (44100*4)
#define SECONDS   (13)

audiosample16_t MyBuffer[AUDIORATE*SECONDS];

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 

    UINT WaveId = 0;
    WaveFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM; // simple, uncompressed format
    WaveFormat.nChannels = 2; // 1=mono, 2=stereo
    WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec = 44100; 
    WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16; // 16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
    WaveFormat.nBlockAlign = WaveFormat.nChannels*WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample/8; 
    WaveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = (WaveFormat.nSamplesPerSec)*(WaveFormat.nChannels)*(WaveFormat.wBitsPerSample)/8; 
    WaveFormat.cbSize=0;

    WaveHeader.lpData = (LPSTR)MyBuffer;
    WaveHeader.dwBufferLength = sizeof(MyBuffer);
    WaveHeader.dwFlags = 0;

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    //std::cout << std::flush;
    HRESULT hr;
    if(argc>1)
        hr= waveInOpen(&hWaveIn,WaveId,&WaveFormat,0,0,CALLBACK_NULL);
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    //std::cout << std::flush;
    return 0;
}
```

If you call it from the command line with no arguments, everything prints out fine(several 'Hello World!'s).  If you redirect this to a file `(myprog.exe > blah.txt)` , again, everything works fine and several lines of 'Hello World!' end up in the file as expected.

HOWEVER, if you have an argument (so that `waveInOpen` is called), it will not redirect anything to the file.  The file is empty.  If you don't redirect the output, it'll print out to the command prompt just fine.

UNLESS you uncomment the std::flush lines, then the file isn't empty and everything works fine.

What the heck is going on under the hood that's causing that?  Shouldn't stdout be flushed on exit and piped to the file no matter what?  What is the `waveInOpen()` call doing that screws up the stdio buffering like that?

FWIW, this came to light because we're calling this program from TCL and Python to do audio quality measurements on an attached product and nothing was being read back, even though it would print out fine when run from the command line (and not redirected).

Comment: Could be crashing on exit, before stdout is flushed. Not sure why though. Maybe not calling `waveInClose()` triggers it?

Comment: Agreed, this sounds like a crash is happening (or the process is forcibly exited) prior to flushing to file. You will just have to debug your app and see what is really happening after `main()` exits.

Comment: The wave functions require a gui as they internally use threads/messages.Using them in a console app is bound to create problems.

Comment: definitely not crashing.  my app does 'all the right stuff' with clsoing things out.  this just was the 'minimal thing' that demonstrated the problem

Comment: FWIW I tried your example here and it doesn't reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: @JonathanPotter huh.  Windows 7 or Windows 10?  We're mostly using windows 7 in our development environment and haven't checked it on windows 10.

Comment: This was on Windows 10.